# rewrite onerorr function of img tag in onerror function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here I have one  tag  to show images;
I want it displays like this:
if exists 1.jpg,show 1.jpg.
else if exists 2.jpg show 2.jpg
else show 3.jpg

```
<img src="1.jpg" onerror="this.scr='2.jpg';this.onerror='this.src=3.jpg'" />
```

it got error; but is it  possible to do this?

Comment: You're nesting quotes too much, and `this.src=3.jpg` ends up being a syntax error. The `error` event does not play well with unobtrusive event handling, but it looks like your only option.

Comment: `this.onerror` should be set to a function, not a string. You might want to set it as a function in JS.

Answer (score 2):

Put the handler in a separate JS function:

```
function image_failover(img) {
    img.onerror = function() {
        img.src = '3.jpg';
    }
    img.src = '2.jpg;
}

<img src="1.jpg" onerror="image_failover(this)" />
```

With the above function, you can cascade as many nested `onerror` handlers as you want. Although if it gets long, you probably should put all the images in an array, and just have the handler increment an index each time it's called.

Comment: What matters is that the attribute contains Javascript code. Escaping works in JS.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you're right. I've changed the answer to just recommend the separate function.